# What printer can output photo-album pages on thick paper?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, printing, paper, printed-album

I wish to obtain a printer that can print photo-album pages on thick paper.

I'd be grateful to hear from anyone who has any information regarding printers that can do this or a reference to a site or people who may be able to help.

Comment: What's your budget? ($400 - $20,000) Nay other parameters? Do you require archival quality? What about the accuracy of colour reproduction?

Comment: As Jakub asked, we would really need to know your budget. There are printers that have larger platen gaps, and some that allow you to adjust the platen gap. Platen gap is the distance between print head and paper surface...a critical factor in accurate dot placement, and one that can be affected by thicker papers. If you use papers that are too thick in a printer that has a smaller platen gap, the print head might scrape the paper, damaging the print or even the print head. Printers that either have large platen gaps or that allow platen gap adjustment tend to be expensive.

Comment: ^^ it's not just the platen gap that is important. For very thick/stiff papers (such as photo-album pages), a straight feed path is essential.

Comment: @djangodude: Very true...I kind of ran out of space to type that, and had to head off to a meeting, but absolutely, you never want to send a thick paper through a curved paper path. It will break the paper base, either causing it to get jammed, or worse, shred as it is pulled through the printer (which can really screw things to hell.)

Comment: I use Canon 9000 Mk II. Quite happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how thick the paper you're talking about is, but I have a Canon Pixma Pro9000, and because it has a straight paper path as an option, I can run large (13x19") and thick papers through it. I've used some heavy duty papers and not had any difficulties. The printer is not all that expensive for the quality and reliability I've gotten from it.